# JSON Object “undefined” cuando viene de un Query a MySQL, a través de PHP y pasandolo a javascript

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, json, geojson

Mi caso es el siguiente:

Tengo un query de `MySQL` que ejecuto en un `PHP (serv.php)`.

1. ¿Importa el tipo de dato en el que esten guardados los datos en `MySQL`?

Este archivo `PHP`, lo mando a llamar desde un `HTML`, el cual contiene un `javascrit`.

El tema es que cuando el *alert* del objeto **JSON** se muestra, se ve de la siguiente manera:

> {"id":"1","name":"-99.11943554878235,19.495348138993876"},{"id":"2","name":"-99.13200974464417,19.47709181483004"},{"id":"3","name":"-99.13993835449219,19.46855463363436"}

Pero cuando quiero ver el atributo "**name**", me muestra "***undefined***".

**ARCHIVO PHP**

```
<?php
$servername = "xxxxxserver.mysql.database.azure.com";
$username = "user@xxxxxserver";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "mydb";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM table01";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$json="";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $json.=($json==''?'':',').'{"id":"'. $row["id"] .'",'; 
    $json.='"name":"'. $row["name"] .'"}';
}

//$json = "{data: [".$json."]}";

echo json_encode($json); // esto es el JSON que retorna el PHP

$conn->close();
?>
```

**// ARCHIVO HTML**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery.js"></script>       <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script type="text/javascript">

    var res = $.ajax({
       url : 'serv.php', // my php file
       type : 'POST', // type of the HTTP request
       success : function(json){ 
          var obj = JSON.parse(json);
          //var obj2 = JSON.parse(obj);
          console.dir(obj);
          alert(obj);
          alert(obj.name);
       }
    });

    </script>   
</head>
<body>
Hi
</body>
</html>
```

La idea es posteriormente esas coordenadas que contiene el objeto, poderlas usar para colocarlas en un MAPA.

ojala alguien pudiera ayudarme.

Comment: Estas intentando acceder a un arreglo desde `obj.name` por lo que obtienes **undefined**, si quieres acceder a una posicion por ejemplo `obj[0].name` ~ `-99.11943554878235,19.495348138993876` o recorrer el arreglo para obtener todas las coordenadas

Answer (score 1):

```js
let obj= [{"id":"1","name":"-99.11943554878235,19.495348138993876"},{"id":"2","name":"-99.13200974464417,19.47709181483004"},{"id":"3","name":"-99.13993835449219,19.46855463363436"}];

console.log(obj); //para visualizar el array de objetos manda un console.log(), te mostrará la estructura que tiene algo como esto 

//0 > {"id":"1","name":"-99.11943554878235,19.495348138993876"}
//1 > {"id":"2","name":"-99.13200974464417,19.47709181483004"}
//2 > {"id":"3","name":"-99.13993835449219,19.46855463363436"}

//Sabiendo esto puedes seleccionar la clave "name" del indice 0, 1 o 2;

console.log(obj[0].name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Esta fue la única forma en la que pude seleccionar `name`, convertí el `json` con `stringfy` y lo volví a parsear, tienes que agregar la posición del item para poder acceder a la propiedad `name`

```js
   let JsonString = JSON.stringify([{"id":"1","name":"-99.11943554878235,19.495348138993876"},{"id": "2", "name": "-99.13200974464417,19.47709181483004" },{"id": "3", "name": "-99.13993835449219,19.46855463363436"}]);
   
   let mostrar = JSON.parse(JsonString)
    console.log(mostrar);
    console.log(mostrar[0].name);

// para usted seria asi el codigo 

    var obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify([{"id":"1","name":"-99.11943554878235,19.495348138993876"},{"id": "2", "name": "-99.13200974464417,19.47709181483004" },{"id": "3", "name": "-99.13993835449219,19.46855463363436"}]));
    console.log(obj);
    alert(obj);
    alert(obj[0].name);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya realice tu recomendación, pero cuando utilizo el alert(obj[0]) -sin el .atributo- me muestra el primer carácter de la cadena, por ejemplo {, si le cambio a obj[1] me muestra las comillas, obj[3] la leta d... osea esta tomando cada carácter de JSON como un elemento, como si fuera una simple cadena...

a que se deberá???

```js
   let JsonString = JSON.stringify([{"id":"1","name":"-99.11943554878235,19.495348138993876"},{"id": "2", "name": "-99.13200974464417,19.47709181483004" },{"id": "3", "name": "-99.13993835449219,19.46855463363436"}]);
   
   let mostrar = JSON.parse(JsonString)
    console.log(mostrar);
    console.log(mostrar[0].name);

// para usted seria asi el codigo 

    var obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify([{"id":"1","name":"-99.11943554878235,19.495348138993876"},{"id": "2", "name": "-99.13200974464417,19.47709181483004" },{"id": "3", "name": "-99.13993835449219,19.46855463363436"}]));
    console.log(obj);
    alert(obj);
    alert(obj[0].name);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```js
   let JsonString = JSON.stringify([{"id":"1","name":"-99.11943554878235,19.495348138993876"},{"id": "2", "name": "-99.13200974464417,19.47709181483004" },{"id": "3", "name": "-99.13993835449219,19.46855463363436"}]);
   
   let mostrar = JSON.parse(JsonString)
    console.log(mostrar);
    console.log(mostrar[0].name);

// para usted seria asi el codigo 

    var obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify([{"id":"1","name":"-99.11943554878235,19.495348138993876"},{"id": "2", "name": "-99.13200974464417,19.47709181483004" },{"id": "3", "name": "-99.13993835449219,19.46855463363436"}]));
    console.log(obj);
    alert(obj);
    alert(obj[0].name);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```